# Can you export AWStats data to google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, awstats

I just started using google analytics and I wanted to import the exist analytics tool data into GA.
I see that GA has a submenu where one can import data, but i don´t seem to find any export menu in AWStats.
I asked my webmaster before bothering you, but he didn´t have  an idea.
I checked the web and couldn't´t find export related topics.
in the attachment a screenshot of the submenus for AWStats.
Did anybody try this before ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

GA data import cannot create hits, it can just amend already existing hits with additional data. So the answer is pretty much "no".

(You *could* pipe in new hit data via the measurement protocol, but you could not set a date/timestamp and there is a limited hit quota per second, so this would take a long time and you would lose the original time information on your hits, which would probably render the data useless).